# Determining Proper Class Scope PHP

Tags: php, scope

I have a model class ModelHome that is a child of Model ie:

```
class ModelHome extends Model
```

Model is a variable of the Controller class ie:

```
class Controller {

    public $model;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->model = new Model;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to access a method within the Controller class from within a method inside the ModelHome class?

I've tried parent:: and calling the class by name ie Controller::method but I can't seem to find the right scope to access the method I need.

Thanks.

-Vince

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you must have an instance of `ModelHome`. If you make an instance of `Model`, that has not automatically been extended by `ModelHome` just because `ModelHome` exists. So, i guess your `Controller::__construct()` should be:

```
public function __construct () {
    $this->model = new ModelHome;
}
```

However, your `ModelHome` does not know about your `Controller` class/instance. You could make a `__construct` in `ModelHome` that takes a parameter with a link to the controller. Like this:

```
class ModelHome extends Model {

    public $controller;

    public function __construct ($controller) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }
}

class Controller {

    public $model;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->model = new ModelHome($this);
    }
}
```

Now, your ModelHome knows about the controller by using `$this->controller`

Comment: Model is extended by ModelHome is the child classes of Controller ie: $this->model->load('home') which extends the class.  But I think thats a great solution.  I can create a protected variable in Model and simply pass in the controller, then from within ModelHome I can call the parent method, brilliant.  Thanks Alfred.